# Error 4003: can't ssh login into the instance that I created in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using GCP and I created a vm instance, but I can't ssh into the machine. This is the error I am getting:

```
Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed Code: 4003 Reason: failed to connect to backend
```

As I search it is because of `This might mean the instance isn't listening on the port you're trying to connect to or the firewall is closed.`

Here is my firewall config:

[image: 0.0.0.0/0 Deny All]

Comment: 1) Show the command that you are using. 2) Show the firewall rules. Edit your question with these details.

Comment: I have the same problem, but a few minutes ago all was working fine and suddenly stop working and now I can't start the ssh console in any way. Do you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This may not be a complete answer, but at the very least your firewall rules aren't allowing connections on the SSH port.  There should be an ingress rule to allow traffic to the instance on TCP port 22 (SSH) on that VPC network.

Generally, this is automatically created by GCP, on the default network it is typically called "default-allow-ssh", but you can also manually create it in the VPC Network -> Firewall rules tab. Make sure it applies to the instance in question (either through "All targets" or a target tag that matches the instance).  You can read more about [GCP firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) in the documentation.

Likewise, make sure you have an external IP or that you are following one of the options [described here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sshbetweeninstances).

Comment: I have checked all and spend around 5 hours but no luck. My firewall rules are correct. Is there any chance that lunux/apache server has blocked the tcp or ssh access?

Comment: @Jnanaranjan sounds like you have a different question then.  Post it separately with the complete details.

Comment: Well in my case it was ufw enabled, blocking port 22

Answer (score 16):

If firewall rules are ok, you may have blocked port 22 (e.g. by using ufw enable command). If so:

1. Apply a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to running instance (instructions for instance that is already running - in the middle of the page)
2. Key: **startup-script** Value: **sudo ufw allow 22**
3. Stop the instance and start it again

You are done. Use SSH to connect to your instance.

Comment: You are a life saver. That was it. I was following the wordpress installation guide from digital ocean and I used ufw commands a couple times.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create another instance and use the same the snapshot of the instance that is not working and then the external ip address of the not working instance will bounce to the created instance. It works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the web interface you can use the following instructions to enable ssh button on the web interface and ssh through that.

[See instructions to show which permission are needed here](http://wwwhww.news/u/cwSNkeLNXf#How%20to%20give%20access%20to%20%22VM%20Instances%22%20to%20the%20intern%3F%20with%20%40gmail.com%20email%20address%20(GCP))

To solve the actual error:
Please consider adding the IAP-secured Tunnel User IAM role to start using Cloud IAP for TCP forwarding for better performance.

Solution: Add "IAP-secured Tunnel User" @project level for that user.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31475286)

Comment: Added the solution, per your comments. Thanks for the ping.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Steps to solve sudo ufw enable issue]

You might have ufw enabled during command execution blocking SSH login.

1. Go to your VM instance and click it
2. Edit mode
3. Find for Management section
4. Look for Automation section
5. Inside the text box, type "ufw allow 22"
6. Save
7. Stop VM instance
8. Start VM instance
9. Here you go...! Access your SSH login!