# Effect of changing zone on google cloud platform connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, zone

I have set up an ubuntu desktop on a google cloud platform VM instance.
Recently, resources (GPUs) are unavailable in my zone (US central1-a), and I am considering moving to another zone. I am using chrome remote desktop to connect the VM instance. My questions are:

1. Will my chrome remote desktop continue to work after moving to a new region, or would I have to redefine things?
2. Is there a way to know in advance the availability of resources in the new zone? Is there an "educated" way to choose a zone such that resources are more likely available?

Comment: There is no way to know in advance if there will be available resources in a zone. However, these documents provide a good guide on choosing a proper zone and build resilient apps. 

For the chrome rdp, it should work afterwards. On the event that it doesn't, you would have to redefine the networking part of it to match the new region

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources

Comment: Thanks LukeTerro. I moved the instance to a different zone (from us-central1-a to us-central1-b) but now I can't access using the chrome rdp, and not even using ssh. The instance does turn on (becomes green) but I can't make any progress from there. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you follow this guide when changing zones?
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones
It states that during the move, some server-generated properties of your instance and disks will change. Therefore, youll have to check your IP and other settings in the instance

Comment: I did a reproduction of this of moving one zone to another and the chrome rdp and ssh work fine. What errors are you getting for both of them? Have you set the firewall rules for them?

Comment: Yes, I followed the guide to zone changing. I used the suggested automatic version with a command:
 "gcloud compute instances move instance-3 --zone us-central1-a --destination-zone us-central1-b". 
Leaving aside the chrome rdp for now, I can't even get access using ssh. The error I get is :
"Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed. 
Code: 4003
Reason: failed to connect to backend
You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy."
I did not change firewall rules.
I did manage to access the disk by creating a new instance and mounting it to it.

Comment: That's odd, I did a reproduction of it and it worked fine for me. Save the instance in a snapshot, delete the instance, create a new instance with the snapshot in a different zone is what I followed. 
Here's a similar post regarding the 4003 error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450539/error-4003-cant-ssh-login-into-the-instance-that-i-created-in-google-cloud-pla

Also the docs here, Ensure that you have the IAP-secured Tunnel User IAM role applied on the resource you're connecting to by viewing the Identity-Aware Proxy page
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/faq

Comment: It is still not working for me but I will try to play around with this some more.  LukeTerro, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: This is quite odd, can you check your firewall to allow ssh tcp 22? You have to add the network tag of the firewall rule on the VM as well. Also make sure to have the tunnel user IAM role applied. Does it still give you the same error?

Comment: It looks to me like they are OK. I also set up new VM instances in that project and they work fine. I think something got messed up when I moved that instance.  When I look at the VM instance details I see the 50GB disk as"boot read/write" but under "image" I have nothing ("-") instead of ubuntu which was there before.

Comment: maybe you didn't save the snapshot correctly when moving from zone to zone? As it stated in the docs that things can change and you must save a snap of the vm.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I moved to the new zone before creating the snapshot. The disk did move with the VM but something got messed up (like I said, I now see nothing under "image" where it was ubuntu before). since the disk was not lost, I created a snapshot afterwards, and the mounted the disk on to a working VM. I can access the data, but was hoping to get the original VM with the desktop and programs. Perhaps it's to late for that now.