# I can't access my external IP on my Compute Engine instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have recently been using the free trial 90 days of Google Compute Engine (the payment configuration I already have it defined). But since this trial is finished the instance was paused, and I already ran it again, but now I cannot access my instance, not even SSH and when I ping the external IP (which I previously set to static) no response, and apparently this IP is down. What could be happening?

Instance is on but IP is down:

[image]

IP static is ok (don't worry if you see it):

[image]

SSH not responding:

[image]

Ping response:

[image]

Firewall rules:

[image]

Serial Port 1:

[image: Serial port 1]

Comment: I think the default firewall rules restrict incoming (Ingress) ICMP traffic and ... unless you have changed those rules, ping never works without changing rules for Compute Engines.

Comment: I just saw this [article](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/tutorials/tutorial-troubleshooting-workflow), do you think it would help me? Should I create a VPC network?. Although this did not happen to me before, the instance ran without problems, this happened after the trial period expired and I started the instance again.

Comment: What are your firewall rules?

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere I uploaded my current rules

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be caused for several reasons:

- You don't have billing enabled.

According to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#end) if the 90 days after the Free-Trial period started has finished you need to activate billing in order to continue to use CE.

- You have an issue with [firewall rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450539/error-4003-cant-ssh-login-into-the-instance-that-i-created-in-google-cloud-pla).
  In this situation, as suggested the post, I recommend you to try the following things:

1. Create a ingress firewall rule for port 22 and make sure it's applied to the proper instance.
2. If the firewall rules are properly applied, you may have blocked port 22 in your instance. In order to unblock it you could use a [startup](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts) script in order to unable port 22 by runnig `ufw allow 22`.

Comment: Account billing is activated, and I start the instance again. All firewall rules is ok, the problem is that the IP does not respond, so there would be no reason to open a port if the IP does not want to respond

Answer (score 1):

As it seems that the VM config wasn't changed and the Firewall seems correct.

I suggest you to go to the instance details and click in the `Serial Port 1 (Console)` to inspect the serial console logs. With those logs you can investigate further as the OS may no be able to boot properly.

If you are unable to run the instance properly you can still use the disk in another instance to recover the data, [reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh?hl=en#move_boot_disk).

Comment: I followed the step of the reference and I am already running it as a new instance but the problem persists, cannot access compute ssh, Putty returns Time out. Also attach the Serial port log in the main question, I suppose something is happening there?

Comment: Have you checked the Serial Port logs? There you could gather info about the OS, check if is able to run. Regarding new instance, you can create one and use this disk as a secondary disk (not boot disk) to recover the data.

Comment: I put the capture in the first post

Comment: It seems that the instance is not able to boot. You could use the disk as a secondary disk to recover the data or you could investigate that specific message, related [1] [2].

[1]:https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/issues/2333#issuecomment-786129411

[2]: https://serverfault.com/a/1068357/535728