# vm instance failed to connect to backend with ssh

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a VM instance in Google cloud and configured it properly with all the necessary software.  then, I cloned its disk and created a new VM instance, utilizing the cloned disk; however, when I tried to connect ot the new instance via the SSH button, it does not succeed with a code 4003.  Reason: failed to connect with backend.  Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450539/error-4003-cant-ssh-login-into-the-instance-that-i-created-in-google-cloud-pla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an instance does not have a public IP address, SSH in a Browser needs to forward the SSH connection through IAP. The error "failed to connect to backend" indicates that the IAP proxy service was unable to open a TCP connection to the instance.

Ensure you have a firewall rule to allow Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) to connect to port 22 on the instance.

**Create a firewall rule**

To allow IAP to connect to your VM instances, create a firewall rule that:

- applies to all VM instances that you want to be accessible by using IAP. \
- allows ingress traffic from the IP range 35.235.240.0/20. This range contains all IP addresses that IAP uses for TCP forwarding. \
- allows connections to all ports that you want to be accessible by using IAP TCP forwarding, for example, port 22 for SSH and port 3389 for RDP.

**To allow RDP and SSH access to all VM instances in your network, do the following:**

1. Open the Firewall Rules page and click Create firewall rule
2. Configure the following settings: 
   **Name**: allow-ingress-from-iap 
   **Direction of traffic**: Ingress 
   **Target**: All instances in the network 
   **Source filter**: IP ranges 
   **Source IP ranges**: 35.235.240.0/20 
   **Protocols and ports**: Select TCP and enter 22,3389 to allow both RDP and SSH.
3. Click **Create**.

In Case you haven't enable your IAP you may refer on this link [Enabling IAP for Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-compute-howto). You may check/browse also other related IAP guides on the left hand pane.