# In GCP MarketPlace Unable to make SSH connection to Marketplace "Deployment Preview" VM

Tags: image, google-cloud-platform, deployment, marketplace

Having successfully created and deployed an image to the GCP MarketPlace, when attempting to update it with a newly created image of our latest release, when attempting to run the "Deployment Preview" and launching the VM I am unable to ssh to the VM to test its working as expected, as the connection attempt fails with error:

> Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy failed
> Code: 4003
> Reason: failed to connect to backend
>
> Please ensure that:
> your user account has iap.tunnelInstances.accessViaIAP permission
> VM has a firewall rule that allows TCP ingress traffic from the IP range 35.235.240.0/20, port: 22
> you can make a proper https connection to the IAP for TCP hostname: https://tunnel.cloudproxy.app
> You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.

Below are what I have tried based on error messages in the "SSH browser" connection attempt, and suggestions to resolve:

1. Added "IAP TCP forwarding" as detailed at https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#create-firewall-rule
2. Added "iap.tunnelInstances.accessViaIAP" permissions to user account as detailed at https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/managing-access#managing_access_with_the_api
3. Added Automatic Startup Script "ufw allow 22" as detailed at [Error 4003: can't ssh login into the instance that I created in google cloud platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450539/error-4003-cant-ssh-login-into-the-instance-that-i-created-in-google-cloud-pla) and restarted VM

Comment: As mentioned in the [SF thread](https://serverfault.com/a/1036511/963370), try establishing a serial connection to your VM. Try connecting using the command `gcloud compute ssh VM-NAME \  --tunnel-through-iap` in [cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/ssh-using-iap#gcloud).

Comment: I have tried setting up a serial port console connection, and logging in as a user created with the following commands added to the metadata "startup scripts"

#!/bin/bash
useradd USERNAME
echo USERNAME:PASSWORD | chpasswd
usermod -aG google-sudoers USERNAME

but the console login fails with error "Incorrect Login" as if the user account it not being added on startup. Note the VM is Ubuntu 20.04, thus are these commands expected to work with it on startup ?

Comment: I also see these messages in the serial console output indicating the sshd deamon is not starting:

 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
 sshd[1032]: Privilege separation user sshd does not exist
 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.